# Wake-on-LAN quit working with latest kernel (Bionic)

Tags: wakeonlan

WOL was working great on Bionic until yesterday's kernel update. How to diagnose/recover it?

Edit: if set to boot from 4.15.0-23 kernel it works. If set to boot from 4.15.0-24 it does not.

Edit2: WoL can be enabled with

```
sudo ethtool -s [card] wol g
```

but it isn't persistent. Searching for how to set it every boot.

Edit3: Per a comment by Kai-Heng Feng on this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1779899) this was an advertent change! (and therefore not a bug)

```
This is because the fix of LP: #1752772 has one commit [1] that disables WoL by default.
Set WoL explicitly should solve your issue.

[1] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7edf6d314cd061e1d0a1b7bc0b511d64322c3f72
```

Comment: There seems to be another kernel update, linux 4.15.0-25.27, on the way: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bionic-changes/2018-July/date.html. Maybe that'll fix things? But I don't know if there's some sort of changelog for you to look at.

Comment: You can boot an older kernel version from the Advanced Options menu in GRUB

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make this persistent I created a script in /etc/network/if-up.d

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/ethtool -s [card] wol g
```

This re-enables WoL every boot.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: You may be interested that Arch Linux lists 9 ways to make it persistent (except your method :)): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN

Comment: Now there are 10!

Comment: This didn’t work for me in Ubuntu 22.04. However, I was able to create a crontab entry that does the same thing:  In the terminal, enter "sudo crontab -e", then enter the line "@reboot /sbin/ethtool -s [card] wol g" where [card] is replaced with the network interface controller (enp4s0 in my case) found by running "ip a".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Wol is disabled by default in the r8169 module for now, and now we must use userspace tools like ethtool to get it: [#1752772](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1752772) and [r8169 ethernet card don't work after returning from suspension](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bionic-changes/2018-July/015305.html). See also [Wake-on-lan Ubuntu support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan) on getting Wake-on-lan persistent on boot. Or just use nm-connection-editor in Network-manager for that.