# Ubuntu cannot be resumed by WOL after first BOOT (from 4.15->4.19rc)

Tags: suspend, ethernet, resume

Dears,

I've annoying bug with my ubuntu ( tested kernel 4.15.x -> 4.19rc)

**Test Case1 :**

First coldBoot

systemctl suspend

Try to resume by WOL ( not working )

resume by keyboard

systemctl suspend

resume by WOL is working

**Test Case2:**

First coldboot

Systemctl poweroff

Try to resume by WOL ( not working ) -> need to restart by power button

**Test Case3:**

First coldboot

sudo /usr/sbin/rtcwake -v -m mem -s 5

Systemctl poweroff

Resume by WOL works

BUT! if If Systemctl poweroff -> I can't resume by WOL !!!

My Bios is properly configured to access WOL ( and it works the second times , Wakeup properly set in linux :-(

I don't feel it's a driver issue, but more a linux parameter that change from first -> second suspend... 
Could you provide me some guidance ?

Thanks a lot in advance
JP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wake-on-LAN quit working with latest kernel (Bionic)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051822/wake-on-lan-quit-working-with-latest-kernel-bionic)

Comment: no the advised bugfix is applicable for general WOL.