# WOL ethtool systemd service not starting

Tags: systemd, wakeonlan

I want to enable WOL, I have it enabled in BIOS and understand I need to configure a systemd service to re-enable the setting on boot.

> interface is enp3s0 (yes I checked), and script has 775 permissions
>
> using Ubuntu 18.04 desktop

`etc/systemd/system/wol.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Wake-up on LAN

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

When I reboot, `sudo ethtool enp3s0` gives me

```
...
Wake-on: d
...
```

Should be = `wake-on: g`

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [don’t add “SOLVED” to the title](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/250300). In order to mark your question _solved_ in the right way, you may [_accept_ the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick mark (✓) next to it) that helped you. In case the [helpful answer was posted by you](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer), you'll have to wait 2 days before being able to accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wake-on-LAN quit working with latest kernel (Bionic)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051822/wake-on-lan-quit-working-with-latest-kernel-bionic)

Comment: hey @OrganicMarble I found the answer already but I can not yet mark it, (3 hours left) I had to enable wakeonlan in netplan, before I could make the setting persistent, with a service in systemd, it didn't run the service until I enabled wol in netplan first. :-), I've posted my answer at the bottom of the page. Have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWERED!
you need to enable WOL in netplan, **and** configure a service that applies ethtool setting on reboot to specify wich (pubmg) network types wake your computer,

Ubuntu 18.04 does not use `etc/network/interfaces/`, but `/etc/netplan/`.
I didn't knew that you need to add a line in your netplan/yaml file, **wakeonlan :true**

```
      ethernets:
          enp3s0:
                  addresses: [192.168.0.99/24]
                  gateway4: 192.168.0.1
                  wakeonlan: true
                  nameservers:
                    addresses: [192.168.0.1]
```

I found you need to use ethtool command **in combination** with the netplan
`wakeonlan: true` setting. and you need to have a service to make the ethtool command persist

> in systemd/system you can add a script to specify types of WOL
> **I highly recommend only using `g`** (magic packet) because if you specify `pumbg` you are likely to get immediate reboots after shutdown, becuase you accept ping,arp,etc... for waking!

script:
etc/systemd/system/wol.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Wake-up on LAN

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be common enough. I was about to try put the ethtool -s dev wol g command into a script to run when the network connects but then I found in my network connections settings in gnome/cinnamon I had an option for wake on lan to select [x] magic. It now keeps the setting on reboot.

If you can't find it anywhere, this what I was about to try:

https://serverfault.com/questions/54704/how-to-get-ethtool-wake-on-lan-setting-to-stick

Comment: hi hugh. it seems they added a line in network/interfaces but 1804 uses netplan for that instead rigth? I tried adding the line under my config in netplan/yamlfile but the result was: it applied "wake-on g" after reboot, but ignored all other lines (route/ip.) and because of that I had no network connection until i reconfigured gateway route/ ip address, any idea why? example of how my netplan file looked:
  `ethernets:
    enp3s0:
     post-up ethtool s enp3s0 s
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.99
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [192.168.0.1]`

Comment: it seems i have no idea how to format 'enters'  :/