# Can't get computer to Wake On LAN

Tags: networking, suspend, wakeonlan

I'm trying to setup my desktop (which is running 20.04) for WOL. I tried following [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/), [this guide](https://www.lifewire.com/wake-on-lan-4149800), a bunch of other help questions, and even the Arch wiki.

Wake On LAN is definitely enabled in my BIOS. Ethtool says my WOL status is 'g,' which the guides say is the correct status. I have the MAC address for the target machine and a wakeonlan app downloaded to my current machine to send magic packets. I can SSH between the machines, so I know they have a LAN connection.

However, I cannot get the target machine to wake up by issuing the command `wakeonlan [MAC address of target]`

The only thing I haven't looked into is that this is a dual boot machine, so maybe the second OS is messing things up, but I'm always shutting down from the Linux side that I'm working on, so it is my understanding that the OS should leave the machine listening for magic packets.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a step I'm missing?
2. Is there a way to tell what port my network card is listening to and see if the magic packets are reaching it?

Comment: are the two machines connected to same network?

Comment: Make sure you're not running into this problem: https://askubuntu.com/q/1051822/243321

Comment: If you have not disabled Windows "Fast Startup" option, Windows can leave hardware in strange states.

Comment: Are you connected via wired ethernet??