# How to make wake on lan work in Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.4.0-58-generic? RTL8111/8168/8411 driver r8169

Tags: realtek, wakeonlan

The Wake-on-LAN works in Windows 10 both after sleep mode and after shutting down but it does not work in Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.4.0-58-generic RTL8111/8168/8411. My ethernet card is RTL8111/8168/8411 and the installed driver is r8169 as you can see in the output of the following commands. This is a laptop, if it matters.

```
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

#uname -r
5.4.0-58-generic

sudo lshw -C network

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 15
   serial: ************
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physicatiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full ncy=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:4f804000-4f804fff memory:4
```

I have noticed that, even though running `sudo ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g` changes the value of "Wake-on" variable displayed by ethtool from "d" to "g", making this does not make Wake-on-LAN functionality to work. That means, if I take the laptop to sleep mode right after updating the value of "Wake-on" variable from "d" to "g", the computer does not wake up on LAN.

Moreover, if I reboot the computer right after setting the value "g" on the "Wake-on" variable, this variable gets the value "d" back again after a reboot.

Does anyone have any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: This answer shows you a way to re-enable it after every boot. It was not clear to me if that is the only issue you are having. https://askubuntu.com/a/1051894/243321 if it works, but stops working after a reboot, this will fix that.

Comment: I improved the explanation of the problem a bit because I realized the explanation was not clear. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NetworkManager, Try this:
get your connection name

```
sudo nmcli connection show
```

modify it

```
sudo nmcli connection modify id "your connection name" 802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan magic
```

That will modify your connection profile in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

reboot

Comment: Before trying this out I would like to mention my desktop environment in this case is LXDE. Will your suggested solution work considering LXDE is my desktop environment?

Comment: I do not know about LXDE, but it probably uses NetworkManager also. Try the first command. if it works, then you are good to go. Anyway it will not break anything.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried your suggestion by typing `sudo nmcli connection modify id "Wired connection 1" 802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan magic` and rebooted after doing that. Even though the output of the command `nmcli con show "Wired connection 1" | grep wake` is `802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             magic` now, booting on LAN does not work yet. Moreover, for some strange reason, the  output of `sudo ethtool enp1s0 | grep "Wake"`  is still ```Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
```

Comment: Just in case, after trying the above steps, I also launched `sudo nmcli con up id "Wired connection 1` and the output was `Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3)`. This changed the output of `sudo ethtool enp1s0 | grep "Wake"` to ```Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g``` Anyway, this did not fix it either. Moreover, after rebooting, the output of `sudo ethtool enp1s0 | grep "Wake"` got back to `Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d`.

Comment: I just found nmcli and ethtool display things that look like contradictory: ```nmcli connection show "Wired connection 1" | grep wake
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             magic
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --``` VS ```sudo ethtool enp1s0 | grep Wake-on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
```  Does anyone know why WOL is enabled according to nmcli whereas it does not look like enabled according to ethtool?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where my ethernet card was not working.  I updated the kernel to 5.9 and it worked like a charm.