# Xubuntu: WOL does not work when shutdown -h, but works when suspended or hibernated

Tags: networking, xubuntu, suspend, shutdown, wakeonlan

I was trying to get to work Wake on lan on my computer thru ethernet. I got to the point where I have WOL enabled, netplan set so that `ethtool <nic>/Wake-on` is always set to `g`. In BIOS I have both wake on lan and to be sure wake on pcie enabled too. As written in title, WOL does not work when I shutdown computer using `shutdown -h`. But it works when computer is suspended and when it is hibernated using `systemctl shutdown` or `systemctl hibernate`. I can see ethernet port LED blink when pc is suspended/hibernated, but it does not blink when halted.
I suspect something like that netcard power is cut off when halted.

I have Xubuntu 20.04 installed

network driver: r8169

How to make it work when computer is halted?

EDIT: maybe there can be cause in that the computer is all in one (Acer Aspire) with its own specific board and thus there can be different conditions of power management from standard computer.

Comment: Does "halted" mean "shut down"?

Comment: yes it does. I updated my description.

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it applies to your situation https://askubuntu.com/q/1051822/243321

Comment: Thanks but link is about setting Wake-on to "g", which equals to Wake on lan. This is the problem I already solved.