Wake On Lan non working with Realtek RTL8125 ethernet card
I have a Geekom A8 mini PC with Ethernet card
Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)

It seems to work fine except for Wake On Lan. If I boot with a Windows USB key and then shutdown, the WOL works. So I think that the card is fine and it is a problem with the Linux driver.
With Ubuntu 24.04 (kernel 6.8.0-48-generic) the output of ethtool is:
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g

The driver seems to be r8169.
If I enter the BIOS menu and switch off the PC while I am in the BIOS menu, then Wake On Lan works.
Any suggestions?

Are you re-enabling it on every boot? https://askubuntu.com/q/1051822/243321

@OrganicMarble Yes, I have the script in /etc/network/if-up.d. Anyway it does not wake up even after the first shutdown.
